# Manejo de Promesas en consulta doble de Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un gestor de datos de ayudantes para una universidad. Estoy utilizando Cloud Functions para el backend de la app web, Firestore para la base de datos y Hosting de Firebase para el frontend.
En Firestore, tengo un modelo de datos como el siguiente:
[image: Modelo de Base de Datos No sql]
Descripción:
Cursos una es colección, cada uno de sus documentos representa una version del curso y contiene una sub-colección con la ID y el estado de cada participante en ese curso.
Historico es una colección que contiene en cada documento la información personal de cada ayudante. La ID de estos documentos es la que se guarda en cada documento de la sub-colección participantes.

Para poder listar a todos los ayudantes, debo hacer una consulta todas las sub-colecciones de cada curso, luego, iterar sobre ese resultado para usar la ID de cada ayudante para obtener su nombre de la colección histórico.
El código que utilizo para eso (esta es una prueba, el original debería ir en la API REST que corre en las Cloud Functions, pero primero debo hacerlo funcionar localmente) es el siguiente:

```
const firebase = require ("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");

var firebaseConfig = {
    .......
  };

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.firestore();


const readAll = async () =>{
    let iDarray = [];
    let ayudantes = [];
    const participantes = await db.collectionGroup('participantes').get();
    participantes.forEach( participante =>{
        const info = participante.data(); //ID_ayudante, estado y vigencias si tiene
        const version = participante.ref.path.split('/')[1];
        info['version'] = version;
        iDarray.push(info);
    });
    console.log("Se leyeron ",iDarray.length," personas.");

    iDarray.forEach( async (obj) =>{
        const ayudante = db.collection('historico').doc(obj.id).get().then(snap =>{
            const infoAyudante = snap.data(); 

            if(Object.keys(obj).length == 3){ //Si tiene vigencias, tendrá 5 elementos en la información   
                ayudantes.push({data: {nombre: infoAyudante.nombre, estado: obj.estado, version: obj.version}});    
            }
            else{
                ayudantes.push({data: {nombre: infoAyudante.nombre, 
                                    estado: obj.estado, 
                                    version: obj.version,
                                    vigAdmin: obj.vigAdmin,
                                    vigAcademico: obj.vigAcademico
                                    }});
            }
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log("Error: ",err);
        });
    });
    return ayudantes; //En la api rest, será: response.json(ayudantes);
};

readAll().then(res =>{
    console.log(res);
});
```

La salida por consola al ejecutar el código es:

*Se leyeron  100  personas.*

*[]*

Claramente, el código esta retornando la lista ayudantes ANTES de que las consultas a histórico sean resueltas.
Para este caso, en la primera consulta ocupé *await* y en la segunda una *promise con then()* . Se que no es buena costumbre mezclar estos métodos, pero probé usando solo await en ambos casos, o solo promisas con then() y en ambos casos el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: No deberías publicar en tu pregunta tus claves de acceso

Comment: Gracias por el dato, las quité. Pero tengo entendido que suelen ir en los códigos públicos y no debería ser necesario esconderlas.

Answer (score 1):

encontré la solución a mi problema.
[Async y Await en Loops](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/)

En esa referencia explican que forEach() *is not promise-aware,* es decir, no espera por las promesas que se inicien en su interior.

Para la solución, utilicé un ciclo for con contador (muy común), para recorrer el arreglo que contiene las ID. Dejo el código que sirve a continuación.

```
    let iDarray = [];
    let ayudantes = [];
    const participantes = await db.collectionGroup('participantes').get();
    participantes.forEach( participante =>{
        const info = participante.data(); //ID_ayudante, estado y vigencias si tiene
        const version = participante.ref.path.split('/')[1];
        info['version'] = version;
        iDarray.push(info);
    });
    console.log("Se leyeron ",iDarray.length," personas.");
    for(let i = 0; i < iDarray.length; i++){
        obj = iDarray[i];
        const ayudante = await db.collection('historico').doc(obj.id).get();
        const infoAyudante = ayudante.data(); 
        if(Object.keys(obj).length == 3){   
            ayudantes.push({data: {nombre: infoAyudante.nombre, estado: obj.estado, version: obj.version}});    
        }
        else{
            ayudantes.push({data: {nombre: infoAyudante.nombre, 
                                estado: obj.estado, 
                                version: obj.version,
                                vigAdmin: obj.vigAdmin,
                                vigAcademico: obj.vigAcademico
                                }});
        }
    }
    return ayudantes;
```

Comment: En la variable `const ayudante = await db.collection('historico').doc(obj.id).get();`, la puedes usar de esta forma `const ayudante = await db.doc(\`historico/${obj.id}\`).get();`

Answer (score 0):

Parece que tu planteamiento inicial para tratar la asincronía es correcto, pero debes seguir haciéndolo durante cada llamada a la API / base de datos. Añade `await` en los lugares indicados, evitando que la función haga un `return` antes de recibir la información que quieres obtener.

Fíjate que de lo contrario, realizará un `return` antes de la segunda llamada que realizas a Cloud Firestore.

```js
const firebase = require ("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");

var firebaseConfig = {
    .......
  };

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.firestore();


const readAll = async () =>{
    
    let iDarray = [];
    let ayudantes = [];

    const participantes = await db.collectionGroup('participantes').get();
    participantes.forEach( participante =>{
        const info = participante.data(); //ID_ayudante, estado y vigencias si tiene
        const version = participante.ref.path.split('/')[1];
        info['version'] = version;
        iDarray.push(info);
    });
    console.log("Se leyeron ",iDarray.length," personas.");

    // await aquí
    await iDarray.forEach( async (obj) =>{
        // y aquí
        const ayudante = 
            await db.collection('historico')
            .doc(obj.id)
            .get()
            .then(snap =>{
                const infoAyudante = snap.data(); 

                if(Object.keys(obj).length == 3){ //Si tiene vigencias, tendrá 5 elementos en la información   
                    ayudantes.push({data: {nombre: infoAyudante.nombre, estado: obj.estado, version: obj.version}});    
                }
                else{
                    ayudantes.push({data: {nombre: infoAyudante.nombre, 
                                        estado: obj.estado, 
                                        version: obj.version,
                                        vigAdmin: obj.vigAdmin,
                                        vigAcademico: obj.vigAcademico
                                        }});
                }
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                console.log("Error: ",err);
            });
    });
    return ayudantes; //En la api rest, será: response.json(ayudantes);
};

readAll().then(res =>{
    console.log(res);
});
```

La asincronía al principio puede ser un dolor de cabeza, pero si la interiorizas, acaba siendo bastante intuitiva.

Comment: Estimado agradezco la respuesta ! Pero, tengo entendido que no se puede usar _await_ para un forEach. Lo intenté y ocurre exactamente lo mismo. Pero es ese exactamente el problema, como lograr que la función 'espere' a que termine ese forEach antes de retornar la lista.

Comment: Considera utilizar la función map entonces .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop